# Power bi subtraction of dates

Tags: date, powerbi, formula, measure

if I have two dates in the following format "28-SEP-2018 12.40.00" in separate columns, does anyone know how can I create a new third column which can produce the result of the formula below.

(0.1+sum(DATE_1)- sum(DATE_2))/(0.1+sum(DATE_2))*100

Comment: How do you interpret the sum of a date column?

Comment: Sum of the date column is the sum of the whole column

Comment: Adding dates is rather unusual. What is the purpose of this new column? Some sort of index or ranking?